# Mask xarray dataset using a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, geopandas, rasterio, xarray, open-data-cube

I have used xarray on some satellite data that I'd like to mask it using a shapefile. I have previously been doing this using a combination of PIL, numpy and gdal, but it would be cleaner to do this directly on the xarray dataset with Rasterio and GeoPandas.

I have the following xarray Dataset:
[image]

Which looks as follows:
[image]

I've opened my shapefile in GeoPandas using:

```
sf = geopandas.read_file('GRI_jergetal.shp')
```

[image]

I then want to mask my xarray dataset using the shapefile in GeoPandas, and it seems like `rasterio.mask.mask` has this capability. However, the code that I have used gives the following error (adding in a nodata and a transform attribute to my xarray as it did not contain those parameters originally).

```
sf = sf.to_crs('EPSG:32643')
ndvi.attrs['nodata'] = np.nan
ndvi.attrs['transform'] = good_ds.affine
rasterio.mask.mask(ndvi.isel(time=0), sf.loc[0, 'geometry'])

[Output]:
`TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not iterable`.
```

I've tried a method posted in a previous post [Python mask NetCDF data using shapefile (xarray & GeoPandas)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289775/python-mask-netcdf-data-using-shapefile-xarray-geopandas) & [Mask Rasterio raster with GeoPandas shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337983/mask-rasterio-raster-with-geopandas-shapefile), but the method doesn't seem right for my present case. Have I made a mistake in invoking the `rasterio.mask.mask()` function or should I try a different method for getting this to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python mask netcdf data using shapefile (xarray & geopandas)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289775/python-mask-netcdf-data-using-shapefile-xarray-geopandas)

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code/text data. Use the `{}` code formatting button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can to use the `rasterio.features.geometry_mask` function to do this:

```
ShapeMask = rasterio.features.geometry_mask(sf.iloc[0],
                                      out_shape=(len(ndvi.y), len(ndvi.x)),
                                      transform=ndvi.geobox.transform,
                                      invert=True)
ShapeMask = xr.DataArray(ShapeMask , dims=("y", "x"))

# Then apply the mask
NDVImasked = ndvi.where(ShapeMask == True)
```

I think from your code snippet above `sf` is a geopandas dataframe. If that's the case, then you need to grab just the polygon you want to apply as the mask (as per `sf.iloc[0]` above).

Answer (score 11):

[Masking NetCDF time series data from shapefile using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354782/how-to-mask-netcdf-time-series-data-from-a-shapefile-in-python/354798#354798)

You can use rioxarray. Here is an example: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html

```py
import rioxarray
import geopandas

geodf = geopandas.read_file(...)
xds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(...)
clipped = xds.rio.clip(geodf.geometry.values, geodf.crs)
```

Comment: What does `mapping` refer to here?

Comment: It is no longer needed. You can see the import in the referenced link.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using Digital Earth Australia's [xr_rasterize](https://github.com/GeoscienceAustralia/dea-notebooks/blob/916db231dcb3698e57b0b2c53b6c751f2ab40e06/Scripts/dea_spatialtools.py#L158) function to convert your geopandas geodataframe into an xarray object, and then use xarray's `.where()` method to mask  you're array.

e.g.

```
mask = xr_rasterize(gdf, da)
masked_da = da.where(mask)
```

If you would prefer to use `rasterio.features.geometry_mask`, then the following code should work. You may need to adjust how you grab the transform information if your dataset does not have a `ds.geobox` attribute (an open data cube query object will have this attribute)

```
import xarray as xr
import geopandas as gpd

#open your shapefile and xarray object
ds = xr.open_dataset('your_dataset')
gdf = gpd.read_file('your_shape.shp')

#convert the geometry of a single polygon in your gdf (adjust the index, [0], to match the row of the dataframe you care about)
geom = geometry.Geometry(
            gdf.geometry.values[0].__geo_interface__, geometry.CRS(
                'epsg:4326'))

# create polygon mask
mask = rasterio.features.geometry_mask(
            [geom.to_crs(ds.geobox.crs) for geoms in [geom]],
            out_shape=ds.geobox.shape,
            transform=ds.geobox.affine,
            all_touched=False,
            invert=False)

mask = xr.DataArray(mask, dims=("y", "x"))

#mask ds with rasterized gdf
ds = ds.where(mask == False)
```

Comment: The `rasterio.features.geometry_mask` code can probably be simplified a bit further to use the `geometry` column of the `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` directly:

https://gist.github.com/robbibt/216d01b92aab9b5f92bd4473e374b270

Comment: Is geometry a separate module?